# remove sidebar separator and reduce widgets margin

Tags: css, wordpress, widget, margin

I am trying to remove the grey lines between sidebar widgets and then reduce the margin between the widgets. I already tried to remove the separator which didn’t work.

```
.sidebar.sidebar-left{
  border:none;
}
.widget{
  border:none;
}
```

I did manage to reduce the margin-top between widgets like this: ( this reduced the margin-top which is probably because my language settings are hebrew ).

```
.widget {
  margin-bottom: -50px
}
```

all other things with margin and padding didn’t help.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please provide a link to your website or it will be difficult to help.

Comment: Please review [how do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and a how to create a [**minimal,reproducible example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we can see the problem and be able to help. You could add a link as @AndyTschiersch suggested, but please note that this isn't enough on its own - questions must be self-contained and include all the relevant information. External links can break or change over time and make the question invalid and unhelpful to future users.